# mv renaming filename to _*_

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Given an example that my file name is
A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ_11111111_1111111111_111111_AB.dat.meta

i am trying to rename this with unix command but when i tried using this cmd

`for f in *.meta; do mv "$f"  "$(echo $f|sed s/[0-9]/?/g|sed 's/-/*/g')" ; done`

my file is renamed to

```
A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ_????????_????????????????????_???????_AB.dat.meta
```

it is expected to rename the file to

```
A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ__????????_????????????????????_*_AB.dat.meta
```

Im quite new with unix cmd , any approach that i should try ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to include `*`s in your filenames although it is technically possible. Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: Because in the folder, i would need to rename all files that has extension of .meta . so instead of doing renaming individual, i will do it with just one function

Comment: I understand you need renaming. I am curious why you need to include `*` in the filenames. It may conflict with `file globbing` and you need to pay attention and extra labor to handle them correctly after renaming. (The character `?` also has the similar risk.)

Comment: Why did `_` got replaced by `__` and how did the middle `????????` count increased?

Answer (score 1):

Since `[0-9]` and `?` are undergoing filename expansion, you should quote them to avoid nasty error messages. With this in mind, I did a

```
 echo A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ_11111111_1111111111_111111_AB.dat.meta | sed 's/[0-9]/?/g'|sed 's/-/*/g'
```

and got as output *A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ*????????*??????????*??????*AB.dat.meta*, which makes sense to me. Why would you expect an asterisk in the resulting filename? In your second *sed* command, you are turning the hyphens into asterisks, but there is no hyphen in the input.

Of course it is pretty unsane to use question marks and asterisks in a file name, as this is just begging for trouble, but there is no law that you must not do this.

Answer (score 1):

> A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ_11111111_1111111111_111111_AB.dat.meta

Match it with a regex. Remember which characters need to be escaped in sed. Remember about proper quoting - if you write `$` it should be inside `"`. Note that if there are no files named `*.meta` it will just iterate over a string `*.meta` unless `nullglob` is set.

```
$ touch A_BC_DEF_GH_IJ_LMNO_PQ_11111111_1111111111_111111_AB.dat.meta
$ for f in *.meta; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/[0-9]/?/g;  s/_\(?*\)_\(?*\)_\(?*\)_\([^_]*\)$/__\1_\2_*_\4/')" ; done
```